# Salesforce Bulk api InvalidBatch : Field name not found

Tags: salesforce, bulk-load

I am using the bulk upload code described at http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/.

The only difference is that i am uploading a custom object type.  I can access Employee_c. But now i get a different error

stateMessage='InvalidBatch : Field name not found : First Name'

First Name is the first column in the csv.

While debugging i can see that the temp csv is being created correctly. However i get this error when  checkResults executes. The code is exactly the same as in the sample java code for bulk api using REST.

I am using the free developer version of salesforce.

I created a new permission set where i have given following permissions on custom object employee:
Read/create/edit/delete/view all/modify all. 
All fields are given edit permissions. 
The permission set is associated with salesforce user license. 
The programmatic login is with a user associated with System administrator profile , which has sales force user license.

But still the error persists!

Any pointers would be appreciated

Thanks

Sameer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try "FirstName" without the space.

You can view the API name of any field in Setup > App Setup > Objects > (Select Your Object) > (Select Your Field). Make sure all the fields you are querying have the correct API names.

Comment: I checked out the API name as specified by you. It was First_Name__c. Modified csv appropriately. It worked! Thank you Sameer